# Why would WaitForSingleObject miss a signal?

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, synchronization, waithandle

It appears that sometimes `WaitForSingleObject` will wait for timeout even though the Event  has been signalled.

The signalling thread receives success from `SetEvent()` every time.  However, the thread being signalled won't always hear the signal.  If I add a redundant `SetEvent()` to the signalling thread the issue will go away.

Obviously something is amiss here.  What are the possible causes?

```
// Signalling Thread
if (SetEvent(waitEvent))
    consoleprintf(L"\r\nEvent Set.");
```

And the should wait for a delay time *or* gets signalled.  But doesn't always get signalled.

```
waitEvent = CreateEvent( 
    NULL,               // default security attributes
    FALSE,               // auto-reset event
    FALSE,              // initial state is nonsignaled
    TEXT("WaitEvent")  // object name
    ); 

for(;;)
{
   dwWaitResult = WaitForSingleObject(waitEvent, // event handle
        5000);    

  switch (dwWaitResult) 
  {
    // Event object was signaled
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        consoleprintf(L"\r\nSuccess.");
        break; 

    case WAIT_FAILED:
    //break;
    case WAIT_ABANDONED:
        consoleprintf(L"\r\nWait failed.");
        break;
    case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
        consoleprintf(L"\r\nWait Timed out: %d", waitTime);
        break;
          default: 
        break;
   }
}
```

Comment: There is no `SetEvent` on the side thread between `ResetEvent` and `WaitForSingleObject` on the thread in question. This matches your description and the likely reason of the mentioned behavior.

Comment: Also, conversely, call `ResetEvent` right after `WaitForSingleObject` - otherwise a Set that happens during the console print might get clobbered by the Reset.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError this problem existed even when the event was auto-reset.  Would this still make sense?

Comment: Did you take the ResetEvent call out, then?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError the ResetEvent() call came after conversion to manual reset.  I'll edit the Q so we're not hung up over reset().

Comment: And you're sure there are no other threads waiting on the same event?

Comment: @JimMischel that would cause this, but there are only two threads.  VS is telling me that as well.

Comment: Since you gave the event a name, it's possible that some other process is eating your signal. Is there a reason you created a named event? Use an anonymous event if possible.

Comment: @RaymondChen Nice hit.  Would you turn that into an answer for SO's sake? Changed the name and it's fine.  Also found the culprit process.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you are creating a named event, the event is accessible to other processes which know the name. That other process may be waiting on the event as well, causing it to eat the signal. Unless there is some reason that the event needs to be visible to other processes, you should pass `NULL` as the event name. That creates an anonymous event which other processes cannot access.

Note that if give the event a name, then you will have the problem that if two copies of your program are running, they will both be using the same event, which will create this same problem.

Comment: Common error. The documentation for CreateEvent used to stink back in the NT4 days.

Comment: @RaymondChen I am seeing a similar problem but I am not using a named event. Can you please take a look?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64174004/missing-event-signal