# Missing event signal?

Tags: c++, winapi, usb, hid

I am trying to send a message to an external device and receive a message from it, via USB.

It is working fine with HidD_GetInputReport() and HidD_SetOutputReport(). The issue is that when I have sent a command, I have some temporary delay in place because the device I am talking to takes some time to respond and fill up the reply buffer. We want to get rid of that delay.

I looked at the option of using the ReadFile() and WriteFile() APIs.

I do a WriteFile like this:

```
DWORD       bytesRead;
OVERLAPPED osWrite = { 0 };
osWrite.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
bool success = WriteFile(Device, packetBuffer, packetLength, &bytesRead, &osWrite);
if ( false == success )
{
    WaitForSingleObject(osWrite.hEvent, INFINITE);
    if (!GetOverlappedResult(Device, &osWrite, &bytesRead, TRUE))
    {
        printf("write failed \n");
        GetErrorMessage();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("write passed \n");
    }
    success = TRUE;
}

CloseHandle(osWrite.hEvent);
```

WriteFile works fine. The device I am talking to receives my message and then responds.

I then do a ReadFile() to get that information. Here is the code snippet for that:

```
DWORD       bytesRead;
OVERLAPPED osReader = { 0 };
    
osReader.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

bool success = ReadFile(Device, packetBuffer, packetLength, &bytesRead, &osReader);
    
if ( success == false)
{
    if (!GetOverlappedResult(m_hDevice, &osReader, &bytesRead, TRUE))
    {
        GetErrorMessage();
    }
}
```

We do receive a response as well. So, it is working fine and dandy but sometimes (for some particular commands) if the device takes a while to respond, it seems the host side keeps waiting for the signal and never moves on. I have verified that device is responding eventually (say after 10 seconds), but it seems host never gets the signal. I am using anonymous event to make sure it doesnt get eaten by any other process.

So, we are just stuck on `if (!GetOverlappedResult(m_hDevice, &osReader, &bytesRead, TRUE))`

Can anyone provide any input as to what I am missing, or if there is something that seems incorrect?

FWIW, this is how i am creating the device

```
 Device = CreateFile( Path,
                            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                            FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                            NULL,
                            OPEN_EXISTING,
                            FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                            NULL);
```

Comment: your code is wrong in any case. you not check result or I/O. call `GetOverlappedResult` exist sense only in case `ERROR_IO_PENDING` returned by I/O. also why you open file with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` but by fact use synchronous I/O ?

Comment: @RbMm I am aware that overlapped and synchronous I/O doesnt really go well together as it defeats the purpose of overlapped I/O. It is just a requirement for now, and should not cause any issues with the normal operation. I did check the readfile response, it is not included here though, and it is ERROR_IO_PENDING. Besides that, do you see any issue which would cause it to not get signaled?

Comment: *I did check the readfile response, it is not included here though* - why you not post actual code in this case ? concrete code in post is wrong. if read or write return false - you need at begin call `GetLastError()`. for what you yet call `WaitForSingleObject` after read (senseless) and not do this after write. again - or use real asynchronous I/O - not wait in place after I/O or remove `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag.

Comment: @RbMm your response is incoherent and not helpful. You are finding minor details in the code that I dont think affects the functionality in general, but yes, should be there to catch cases where it fails. As I mentioned before, I am aware that using waitforsingleobject with timeout defeats the purpose of asynchronous I/O

Comment: i think this is not minor details. why is `GetOverlappedResult` is wait infinite ? in **concrete** code - if `ReadFile` fail but not with `ERROR_IO_PENDING` - *osReader.hEvent* will be not set, as result and `GetOverlappedResult` infinite wait

Comment: @RbMm I agree with you completely, but please understand that I just posted snippet of major code and these details will be handled. As indicated before, ReadFile doesnt fail, it is just in cases where device we are talking to takes a while to respond, we just dont catch that signal, I dont know why though. I can change the posted code to add the check for Error_io_pending, but the behavior still remains the same.

Comment: but how by this code possible give you answer ? try set self on place of readers. os set event passed to I/O request only in case device return `STATUS_PENDING` and then call `IofCompleteRequest`. now exist case when device return some error code, and as result `ReadFile` return false. `GetOverlappedResult` wait on event because `ReadFile` set `STATUS_PENDING` in `osReader` but *hEvent* never been set in this case. i not view another reason of infinite waite

Comment: miss event in `GetOverlappedResult` impossible. if `GetOverlappedResult` wait infinite - this mean that `osReader.hEvent` not set. and this mean that I/O still not finished or it **synchronous** finished (last error not `ERROR_IO_PENDING`). *I have verified that device is responding eventually* - how ?!

Comment: on what answer you wait here ?

Comment: @RbMm I have not gotten the answer as to why the hEvent is not getting set. It is working for normal cases, but in situations when the device I am talking to takes more than 5 seconds to respond, we never get hEvent back. So something is going on when we take a while to respond, some sort of timeout, and I am trying to find that.

Comment: @RbMm The device I am talking to is working fine, and I can step through the code, they do respond to our original request, the host is hung because of lack of hEvent, and after timeout I checked the handler is still valid. In cases where we send the message and we get response within 5 seconds, everything works okay, but as soon as command takes more than 5 seconds, we are stuck. So, something is getting timed out.

Comment: `hEvent` not set if request not completed or if it failed **synchronous** (i/o return false, but last error not status pending). based on your code and info - **impossible** give another answer. *they do respond to our original request* - this point is absolute unclear